# Querying User Table when Twilio number is called

Tags: express, parse-platform, twilio

I use Parse.com as backend service. When someone calls the twilio number I want to detect the callers phone number in cloud code and then query the corresponding user phone number. I was able to get the callers number by request.param('From') however I failed querying that user. I tried querying inside the /hello function in many forms but it did not work. I have used the same set of querying that works for other cloud functions. The query logged as undefined. Why that happens?
Xcode:

```
 NSString *callString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://twilioNumber"];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:callString]];
```

Parse Cloud Code

```
    //Someone calling twilio number
    app.get('/hello', function(request, response) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse('');

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("PhoneNumber", request.param('From'));
    query.first({
            success: function(result) {
            var foundusr = result;
        var receiver = foundusr.get("Receiver");
twiml.dial({callerId:'twilioNumber'}, receiver);
},
            error: function(error) {response.error("Error updating user passcode"); 
});    
        response.type('text/xml');
        response.send(twiml.toString(''));
        });
        app.listen();
```

Comment: Can you please post a full example of your code where you attempt to pull extract the callers number, and perform a query for this number. The code you posted does appear to be doing this, so it is hard to point you in the right direction at this point.

Comment: ardrian I edited my codes. the request.param('From') extracts the caller number.

Comment: @ardrian when I do twiml.dial({callerId:'twilioNumber'},request.param('From')); it calls back the caller. So the only problem is at querying the User table. In console it says that foundusr is undefined.

Comment: foundusr will be undefined in the cases where the query succeeded, but found no matches. You should check that foundusr is defined before you call the dial method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work because because the following code was not inside the query.first function

```
twiml.dial({callerId:'twilioNumber'}, receiver);
                response.type('text/xml');
```

So the right way to do it is

```
//Someone calling twilio number
        app.get('/hello', function(request, response) {
        var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse('');

var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("PhoneNumber", request.param('From'));
    query.first({
            success: function(result) {
            var foundusr = result;
            var receiver = foundusr.get("Receiver");
            twiml.dial({callerId:'twilioNumber'}, receiver);
            response.type('text/xml');
        response.send(twiml.toString(''));
},
            error: function(error) {response.error("Error updating user passcode"); 
});    

        });
        app.listen();
```

Comment: Glad you found your mistake. You should still check to make sure result is defined, to handle the case where no number is found.